# Switching from MSTest to another unit test framework in VS 2010

Tags: unit-testing, mstest, googletest

Visual Studio 2010 offers a lot of comfortable tools for unit testing via its built in test runner. Unfortunately we can't use MSTest for our unmanaged c++ codebase. Is it possible to switch from MSTest to e.g. Google.Test and have it integrated with the built in Visual Studio test runner?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not seen anyway to integrate another unit testing framework into the VS test runner.

You might look at some VS add-in test runners, [testdriven.net](http://testdriven.net) and [gallio](http://www.gallio.org/) are two.

Kindness,

Dan

Comment: Thanks for your comment!
Are you speaking of Visual Studio 2008 or VS 2010? As far as I know is the Test Runner in 2010 now stand alone.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use gtest (google test) in VS2010 and have it integrated with the IDE thanks to the extension: [GoogleTestAddin](http://googletestaddin.codeplex.com/)

You can be interested by this similar thread: [Viewing Google Test results within Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5154866/viewing-google-test-results-within-visual-studio)